# Где заканчивается деепричастный оборот?

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите определить границы деепричастного оборота!

Заложенные в конструкцию инновационные идеи позволяют затвору не только выполнять функции перекрытия и регулирования потока среды, обеспечивая требуемые параметры (,) даже когда другие этого не могут сделать, но при этом иметь более низкую стоимость.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас не хватает какого-то слова после другие. Ну или там напрасно опущено повторяющееся "идеи"...

Я воспринимаю фразу так

*Заложенные в конструкцию инновационные идеи позволяют затвору не только выполнять функции перекрытия и регулирования потока среды, обеспечивая требуемые параметры даже когда другие **[методы]** этого не могут сделать, но **и иметь при этом** более низкую стоимость.*

Здесь границы оборота очевидны. так что и в исходном варианте спорная запятая не нужна.
А вот надо ли править стиль - этот вопрос решается по ситуации. Если можно, то, конечно, лучше исправить.

(+)---

Ха, оказывается именно это уже предлагали. Ну тогда тем более стоит поверить.

Comment: Наверное, вместо "методы" лучше написать "факторы"

Comment: Спасибо. Мне эта запятая и казалась ненужной. И насчет исправления тоже согласна. Так фраза имеет более четкий вид.

Comment: >Наверное, вместо "методы" лучше написать "факторы"
  
Не... Ну когда это факторы что-то "делали"? Они максимум *влияюют*. 
Если не методы, то **решения**, **технологии**, **приемы**. Что-то из этого ряда. 

Тут, имхо, другое. Коли уж придираться, то к "выполнять функции перекрытия". Могут идеи "выполнять фунции"? А если могут, то что это за "функция перекрытия"? Я-то это пропустил, как не относящееся к конкретному вопросу.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, у Вас пропущена вторая часть двойного союза, даже ТОГДА, когда. Тогда все становиться на свои места, после параметра нужна запятая, так как но закрывает деепричастный оборот.

Comment: Она, эта вторая часть, здесь совсем не обязательна. А причина невосприятия текста несколько в другом. см. мой ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с ответом Юлии и, в качестве дополнения, позволю себе предложить вам сделать  небольшую корректировку в конце предложения: **но и иметь при этом более низкую стоимость**. В этом случае, на мой взгляд, связка основной функции с акцентом на более низкую стоимость выглядит чётче.